# Passing a data pointer from an anonymous temporary

Tags: c++11

Is this code C++11 standards-compliant?

Function prototype:
`void foo(double[] arr);`

Caller: `foo(std::vector<double>{0.0, 1.0, 2.0}.data())`

In detail: what I'm doing is creating an *anonymous temporary* `std::vector<double>`, extracting the data (a `double*`) and passing that to an old-style function `foo`. (`foo` knows in advance the size of `arr`). But does it work for every calling convention? I have concerns that the `.data` pointer may be invalidated if the vector is popped from the calling stack before I'm done with its contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fine; temporaries are destroyed at the end of evaluation of a full-expression (12.2p3), so the `vector` will live at least for the duration of the call to `foo`.